# Create Dynamic Subdomains using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am developing an application using Spring , jsp and Apache 7.0 server, now suppose i have register domain such as "www.example.com" and in my application the user fills the registration form in which the user is ask to enter his url to name such "123" as soon he submit the form after filling details i want to redirect the him to the newly created URL now in our case "123.example.com"

Now at this movement i have to create sub domain in my code itself before he gets redirected. I have gone through google not find much.

Any help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would need an API to submit a DNS update to your DNS host. And then wait for it to propagate across the Internet.

Comment: @JimGarrison: Subdomains don't have to propagate. They're ready immediately upon creation.